# SQL INSERT or UPDATE in statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and I want to create an INSERT or Update query for my webpage. I have two buttons, Status and Shipped, next to every item. If the user presses one of these buttons, it calls a php file with a query. But I really dont know how to put together these 2 queries into 1.

| Items | STATUS | SHIPPED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | STATUS | SHIPPED |
| Item2 | STATUS | SHIPPED |
| Item3 | STATUS | SHIPPED |

Status Button

```
   IF status NOT EXIST WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
    THEN INSERT INTO table1 VALUE (status = 1) WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
    BUT, IF shipped = 1 AND status = 0 WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
        THEN UPDATE table1 SET status = 1
```

Shipped Button

```
 IF shipped NOT EXIST WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
    THEN INSERT INTO table1 VALUE (shipped = 1) WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
BUT, IF staus = 1 AND shipped = 0 WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
    THEN UPDATE table1 SET shipped = 1
```

Query to filter out non essecial rows

```
IF status = 0 AND shipped = 0 WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
    THEN DELETE row WHERE user_id = 17 AND item_id = 5
```

Thank you!

Comment: try `INSERT INTO table1 (user_id, item_id, status, shipped)
VALUES (17, 5, 1, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    status = IF(shipped = 1 AND status = 0, 1, status),
    shipped = IF(status = 1 AND shipped = 0, 1, shipped);`

Comment: it keeps adding new rows to the table and not updating it :/